# javascript counter is not increasing counter in each call

Tags: javascript

In the javascript code i was expecting that this function should increment the counter each time it is called but the value is remaining same for each time it is called, that is 1.. why is it not incrementing.

```
 <body>
        <p>increasing the counter</p>
        <button type = "button" onclick="document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = add()">Counter</button>
        <p id = "para"></p>

    <script>
      function add(){
            var counter = 0;
            return counter = counter + 1;
           }
    </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: Lots of good answers below.  Once you have this working, you might also think about using a closure to take **counter** out of the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Define `counter` globally(outside the function) or else every time when function is being called, value of `counter` is set to `0`

```js
var counter = 0;

function add() {
  return counter = counter + 1; //OR return ++counter;
}
```

```html
<p>increasing the counter</p>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = add()">Counter</button>
<p id="para"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take your `counter` variable outside your function definition( i.e. define it as a global variable ), so that it retains its previous value. Otherwise every time you call the function, its value is reset to 0.

```
<body>
        <p>increasing the counter</p>
        <button type = "button" onclick="document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = add()">Counter</button>
        <p id = "para"></p>

    <script>
      var counter = 0;
      function add(){
            return counter = counter + 1;
           }
    </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`counter` is set back to `0` in each call.

In this case counter could just be moved outside of the function:

```js
var counter = 0;
function add(){
    return counter = counter + 1;
}
```

```html
        <p>increasing the counter</p>
        <button type = "button" onclick="document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = add()">Counter</button>
        <p id = "para"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Slightly alter program    
<html>
    <body>
    <script>
    var counter = 0;

    function add() {
      return counter = counter + 1;
    }
    </script>
    <p>increasing the counter</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = add

    ()">Counter</button>
    <p id="para"></p>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `counter` out of the `add()` function. Every time `add()` is invoked the counter is set to ZERO `counter = 0` and then it is returned after incrementing by 1 `return counter = counter + 1`.

```js
var counter = 0;
function add (){
    return counter = counter + 1;
}
```

```html
        <p>increasing the counter</p>
        <button type = "button" onclick="document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = add()">Counter</button>
        <p id = "para"></p>
```

Second Method, if you want to declare `var counter` in `add()` (to avoid polluting global scope ) use JS closure. See following code snippet.

```js
var add = (function (){
    var counter = 0;
    return function() {return counter = counter + 1;}
})();
```

```html
        <p>increasing the counter</p>
        <button type = "button" onclick="document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = add()">Counter</button>
        <p id = "para"></p>
```